# MESH Network on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking

I need to make a mesh network test bid using existing wifi card of laptops on Ubuntu. 
and then run any file sharing or application sharing on that mesh.

I tried [this tutorial](http://www.kwalinux.nl/what-a-mesh/1129/) but failed to paste the `olsrd.config` file to `/etc` folder!

if there is any better way to make a mesh between 3-5 laptops, kindly help me out.

```
fleur@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:de:2b:74:d0:29
inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: fe80::76de:2bff:fe74:d029/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:330 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:57824 (57.8 KB)  TX bytes:41243 (41.2 KB)

fleur@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     
IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"mesh"  
Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Cell: 8E:FA:05:4E:5E:D3   
Tx-Power=16 dBm   
Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=250 B   Fragment thr=256 B   
Power Management:on

fleur@ubuntu:~$ sudo olsrd -d 2
*** olsr.org -  0.6.3-git_-hash_cfd7c48ab5a78db3e70cfdece616addb  - ***
Build date: 2013-04-06 06:14:10 on batsu
http://www.olsr.org

Parsing file: "/etc/olsrd/olsrd.conf"
Debug level: 0
IPv4 broadcast: 255.255.255.255
HELLO interval: 6.00
HELLO validity: 600.00
TC interval: 0.50
TC validity: 300.00
MID interval: 10.00
MID validity: 300.00
HNA interval: 10.00
HNA validity: 300.00

Interface DefaultsLink quality fish eye 1
IpVersion: 4
Clear screen enabled
Noint set to 1
Willingness: 3
IPC host: 127.0.0.1
Hysteresis disabled
Link quality level 2
Pollrate 0.10
TC redundancy 2
MPR coverage 5
No interfaces configured!

Bad configuration!

OLSR EXIT: main
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be root user to access `/etc`!

There are 2 ways to get superuser rights:

- gain root privileges by executing `sudo <command>`
- or switch to root shell and run *command* there: `su` or `sudo su`

Both ways require entering your admin password, so be sure that you are local admin.